# MacBookPro fan constantly on maximum - lots of noise

Tags: macos, macbook-pro

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [MacBook Pro fan running constantly](https://superuser.com/questions/183900/macbook-pro-fan-running-constantly)

My MBP has suddenly started making loads of noise lately.  It sounds like the fan is running full steam.  It was never usually like this.

Any tips to stop it from doing this?

> System Software Overview:
>
> System Version: Mac OS X 10.6.6
>   (10J567)   Kernel Version:    Darwin
>   10.6.0   Boot Volume: Macintosh HD   Boot Mode:   Normal   Computer
>   Secure Virtual Memory:    Enabled
>   64-bit Kernel and Extensions: No
>   Time since boot:  18:58
>
> Hardware Overview:
>
> Model Name: MacBook Pro   Model
>   Identifier:   MacBookPro6,2   Processor
>   Name: Intel Core i7   Processor
>   Speed:    2.66 GHz   Number Of
>   Processors:   1   Total Number Of
>   Cores:    2   L2 Cache (per core):    256 KB
>   L3 Cache: 4 MB   Memory:  8 GB
>   Processor Interconnect Speed: 4.8 GT/s
>   Boot ROM Version: MBP61.0057.B0C   SMC
>   Version (system): 1.58f16   Serial
>   Number (system):  W80208GLAGZ
>   Hardware
>   Sudden Motion Sensor:   State:    Enabled

Comment: @studiohack How could this have been an exact duplicate when the solutions to the problem are totally different? (Here, finding the application through Activity Monitor solved it, the other question deals with external monitors..)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please provide some informations about running processes.

If you start Utilities -> Activity Monitor, you can see the processes running on your system. In the dropdown above, select "All Processes". Sort those by %CPU, so you can find out which process makes heavy use of your CPU and therefore keep your fans running.

[image]

In 99% of all cases, this is the main problem.

Comment: Thanks that seems to have solved the problem.  It was an iPad application running in Xcode simulator.  I think its because I just leave it running while I am coding and then just restart it.  Weird